# Count Multiple Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have multiple models: User, Track, Tutorial, Chapter, Lesson, & SolvedLesson.

Below is what I've done to for counting each model.

```php
$data = [
    'userCount' => \App\User::count(),
    'userRegisteredToday' => \App\User::whereCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d'))->count(),
    'trackCount' => \App\Models\Track::count(),
    'tutorialCount' => \App\Models\Tutorial::count(),
    'chapterCount' => \App\Models\Chapter::count(),
    'lessonCount' => \App\Models\Lesson::count(),
    'solvedLessonCount' => \App\Models\SolvedLesson::count(),
];
```

Laravel provides relationships and eager loading to efficiently query.
Is there any method to convert the above query into one single query for better performance?

Comment: Could you also provide the relationship between this models? I think a couple of counts can be avoided..

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. its just the count of each model in dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method allows you to count the number of results for model relationships.

Assuming you've defined a one to many relation between the `User` and `SolvedLesson` models:

```
// you can optionally alias the appended count attribute
$users = User::withCount('solvedLessons as solved_count')->get();

// total users
$users->count()

// iterate users to get the number of solved lessons for each
$users->each(function (User $user) {
    // using the alias defined above
    echo $user->solved_count;
});
```

You're not limited to a single relation either, passing an array will get the count for each relation:

```
$tracks = Track::withCount(['tutorials', 'users'])->get();

// total tracks
$tracks->count()

// access each relation count per track
$tracks->each(function (Track $track) {
    echo $track->tutorial_count;
    echo $track->user_count;
});
```